# i am trying to access drawer layout id but this giving me error mismatched type of navigationDrawerBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

[here it is giving type mismatched error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT03l.jpg)

i am trying to access drawer layout id but this giving me error mismatched type of navigationDrawerBinding
i included another xml file in activity main

Mainactivity.kt

```
package com.example.project1

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import com.example.project1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.project1.databinding.NavigationDrawerBinding
import com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenu

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var togle:ActionBarDrawerToggle

S
//this is not the part of error so ignore it
    private val sharedPreferernceFile="kotlinSharedPreference"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer)



//error here binding.drawerlayout
        togle= ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,binding.drawerlayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
//included another xml file 
    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"></include>
```

navigation_drawer.xml

Comment: setContentView(binding.root) use this one

Comment: @RudraRokaya ohh that was for testing btw i got the answer in toggle function there should be ````binding.drawerlayout.root``` and that's it. thx

Answer (score 0):

In the toggle function, there should be `binding.drawerlayout.root` and that's it.